# How do you stack pandas series 2D graphs into a 3D structure?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, 3d, 2d

I have some longitudinal data of 1 the weights of 115 patients structured in a dataframe. When I try to plot this however will, as suspected, all graphs be superpositioned on each other making it hardly comprehensible.

Now i would like to graph the individual graphs for each patient NEXT to each other instead of on top of each other; hence creating a 3D plot.

I tried this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = [i for i in range(10)]
for i in range(115):
    y = i
    ax.plot(x, dfm.WOMEN.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area = 'inside').loc[:, i], zs=i, zdir='z')
ax.view_init(elev=-150., azim=1000)

plt.show()
```

And although close this projects the weights on the y axis and each patient is incremented over the z-axis. Making it look a bit weird to me.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlxNE.png] (like so)

Does anyone know how I can project the weights on the z-axis and display my patients on the y-axis?

DATA:
eg. (values are already interpolated beneath)

Patient 1: 
[118.0, 111.0, 104.0, 102.42857142857143, 100.85714285714286, 99.28571428571429, 97.71428571428571, 96.14285714285714, 94.57142857142857, 93.0]

Patient 2:
[108.0, 97.0, 86.0, 75.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0]

Patient 3:
[105.0, 97.0, 89.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0]

Patient 4:
[116.0, 103.5, 91.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0, 85.0]

Patient 5:
[112.0, 108.57142857142857, 105.14285714285714, 101.71428571428572, 98.28571428571429, 94.85714285714286, 91.42857142857143, 88.0, 88.0, 88.0]

Patient 6:
[148.0, 136.33333333333334, 124.66666666666667, 113.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0, 112.0]

Patient 7:
[114.0, 111.0, 108.0, 105.0, 101.66666666666667, 98.33333333333333, 95.0, 91.66666666666667, 88.33333333333333, 85.0]

(i formatted the series in list for easier comprehension here, but in my computer it is in a pandas dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, I can't test this solution, but try switching what you're passing in as `y` and `z`. Something like:

```
ax.plot(xs=x, 
        ys=i, 
        zs=dfm.WOMEN.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside').loc[:, i],
        zdir='z')
```

Also, note that your code defines `y = i`, but `y` is never actually used.

Comment: Thank you but well i tried that but i gave this error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)...

Comment: @Laurens, then in your original code, try changing `zdir='z'` to `zdir='y'`. Also, it would help if you posted some example contents of the DataFrame.

Comment: I tried that already but it only seems to alter the direction of the graphs but the axis stay. I updated my post with the data of the first 7 patients!